# Bulk Import Error

Tags: magento-1.9, import, importexport

I have tried to csv import just 40 products.

But there was an error like keep buffering like the image.

[image]

Then I have uploaded the same content with 10 products per csv file and it was successfully added.

Anybody knows about this error?

Comment: Not really an "answer" - but Magmi has error reporting via email. I've found it's the more reliable way to import products with a lot better control over it's configuration. **kind of an answer** I'd check your PHP memory_limit and timeouts via .htaccess or your php.ini file and extend them both if the site continues to freeze. Also set Indexing to manual and setup a cron job for it - instead of every time `save` is used

Answer (score 0):

PHP likely ran out of some sort of resource. When importing or exporting out of Magento, I always adjust the values for the following PHP settings:

```
upload_max_filesize
post_max_size
max_input_time
memory_limit
max_execution_time
session.gc_maxlifetime
```

This can be done using the php.ini file, or can usually be temporarily overridden in your .htaccess file in the root of your server.